# Parameter tuning/model selection using resampling

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, resampling

I have been trying to get into more details of resampling methods and implemented them on a small data set of 1000 rows. The data was split into 800 training set and 200 validation set. I used K-fold cross validation and repeated K-fold cross validation to train the KNN using the training set. Based on my understanding I have done some interpretations of the results - however, I have certain doubts about them (see questions below):

Results :
**10 Fold Cv**

```
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, 720, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  Accuracy  Kappa     
  5  0.6600    0.07010791
  7  0.6775    0.09432414
  9  0.6800    0.07054371

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 9.
```

**Repeated 10 fold with 10 repeats**

```
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  Accuracy  Kappa     
  5  0.670250  0.10436607
  7  0.676875  0.09288219
  9  0.683125  0.08062622

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 9.
```

**10 fold, 1000 repeats**

```
  k  Accuracy   Kappa     
  5  0.6680438  0.09473128
  7  0.6753375  0.08810406
  9  0.6831800  0.07907891

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was k = 9.
```

**10 fold with 2000 repeats**

```
  k  Accuracy   Kappa     
  5  0.6677981  0.09467347
  7  0.6750369  0.08713170
  9  0.6826894  0.07772184
```

**Doubts**:

1. While selecting the parameter, `K=9` is the optimal value for highest accuracy. However, I don't understand how to take `Kappa` into consideration while finally choosing parameter value?
2. Repeat number has to be increased until we get stabilised result, the accuracy changes when the repeats are increased from 10 to 1000. However,the results are similar for 1000 repeats and 2000 repeats. Will it be right to consider the results of 1000/2000 repeats to be stabilised performance estimate?
3. Any thumb rule for the repeat number?
4. Finally,should I train the model on my complete training data (800 rows) now test the accuracy on the validation set ?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Accuracy` and `Kappa` are just different classification performance metrics. In a nutshell, their difference is that `Accuracy` [does not take possible class imbalance into account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) when calculating the metrics, [while `Kappa` does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa). Therefore, with imbalanced classes, you might be better off using `Kappa`. With R `caret` you can do so via the `train::metric` parameter.
2. You could see a similar effect of slightly different performance results when running e.g. the 10CV with 10 repeats multiple times - you will just get slightly different results for those as well. Something you should look out for is the *variance* of classification performance over your partitions and repeats. In case you obtain a small variance you can derive that you by training on all your data, you likely obtain a model that will give you similar (hence stable) results on new data. But, in case you obtain a huge variance, you can derive that just by chance (being lucky or unlucky) you might instead obtain a model that either gives you rather good or rather bad performance on new data. BTW: the prediction performance variance is something e.g. R `caret::train` will give you automatically, hence I'd advice on using it.
3. See above: look at the variance and increase the repeats until you can e.g. repeat the whole process and obtain a similar average performance and variance of performance.
4. Yes, CV and resampling methods exist to give you *information* about how well your model will perform on new data. So, after performing CV and resampling and obtaining this information, you will usually use *all your data* to train a final model that you use in your e.g. application scenario  (this includes both train and test partition!).